# Changing a variable during a loop, Python

Tags: python, loops, variables, arcpy

So what I have is I am using Python's arcpy for ArcGIS.

I have several variables outside of my loop that point to text field in my ArcMap MXD document.

I then perform a loop that goes through each row of a buffer layer and I then select by location any point layers that are within said buffer.

I want to then take values from these point layers and put populate the text fields that were declared earlier.

My trouble is that I want to iterate the variables so that they point to a different text field each time the loop runs through.

My Code:

Pointing the text elements in my MXD document

```
HarbName1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName1")[0]
HarbName2 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName2")[0]
HarbName3 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName3")[0]
```

The first loop

```
for row in rows_dfA_Asset:
   whereClause = '"HARB_CODE" = ' + str(row.getValue("Harb_Code"))
   arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(dfA_Buffer, output, whereClause, "", "")
   arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(dfA_Layer, "WITHIN", output, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
   test = arcpy.SearchCursor(dfA_Layer, fields="Harb_Code; NAME; CAPACACITY; HIGH_BERTH; HarbHiPerc; AvgBerth; HarbAvgPer; CLSD_DET; CLSD_NUM_M; Tot_Num_As; Num_SCH_As; PROV; GOV_SCORE; MAN_SCORE")
```

The second loop *THIS IS THE ISSUE*

```
for field in test:
    count = count + 1
    print count

    HarbName(count) = str(field.getValue("NAME"))
```

So it boils down to that I need to iterate the variable name which will match up with the global variable that points to be text element.

If anybody could think of way to do this it would be greatly appreciated. I know my code is not the greatest, I am not a programmer by trade.

Comment: Little confused as to what you are trying to do but from what I'm guessing you want a python dictionary.

Comment: @Andrew Is your 2nd loop nested inside the 1st one? If not, in the 1st loop you iterate over some data structure, compute a result (`test`) and then you throw it away, except for the last iteration...  Is this what you're really trying to get?

Comment: @gbofii Yes my 2nd loop is nested within my 1st one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comment is on the right track.

What you want to do is restructure the following:

```
HarbName1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName1")[0]
HarbName2 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName2")[0]
HarbName3 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName3")[0]
```

such as:

```
HarbName = { 1: arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName1")[0],
             2: arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName2")[0]
             3: arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName3")[0]
           }
```

Then the last bit would be along the lines of:

```
for field in test:
    count = count + 1
    print count

    HarbName[count] = str(field.getValue("NAME"))
```

Assuming that count is a zero based and matches the indexes defined above

Comment: You have one `+ 1` too much: after `count = count + 1` (or better: `count += 1`), `count` is `1`. With `HarbName[count+1]`, you start `Harbname`'s indexes with 2...

Answer (score 1):

What you need for this is a list. You can then access each text element by your count. You need to change:

```
HarbName1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName1")[0]
HarbName2 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName2")[0]
HarbName3 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName3")[0]
```

To:

```
HarbNames = []
HarbNames.append(arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName1")[0])
HarbNames.append(arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName2")[0])
HarbNames.append(arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName3")[0])
```

Or, more compact:

```
HarbNames = [arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName1")[0],
             arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName2")[0],
             arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "HarbourName3")[0]]
```

Then, later, in your second loop, do `HarbNames[count]` (assuming `count` is zero-based):

```
for field in test:
    print count

    HarbNames[count] = str(field.getValue("NAME"))
    count = count + 1
```